Average Variance Extracted and Factor loading cutoff not aligning
The cutoff for factor loadings is generally around 0.4 (Stevens 1992), Fidell (2007), 0.32 (poor), 0.45 (fair), 0.55 (good) by follow Comrey and Lee (1992). But for convergent validity you require Average variance extracted of 0.5 or above which implies you factor loading on average should 0.7 or above.
So the difference between them is huge, why is that ?
Further, almost all researches have used PCA as factor extraction method, which in fact its not. By using PCA you get nice loading values which I am getting but with PAF i am not. Still confused which method to go with ?
